# No nmp command to use to install moralis-admin-cli

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to copy the moralis-admin-cli into the the subdirector that the Terminal Program gave to me in Visual Studio Code.
This is how it is supposed to be written as far as the tutorial I am following:
C:\metadata-static-app>nmp install -g moralis-admin-cli. This supposed to load the moralis-admin-cli to my directory.
But there is no nmp command.
I did a help and this what came up:
C:\metadata-static-app>help
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
ASSOC       Displays or modifies file extension associations.
ATTRIB          Displays or changes file attributes.
BREAK           Sets or clears extended CTRL+C checking.
BCDEDIT         Sets properties in boot database to control boot loading.
CACLS           Displays or modifies access control lists (ACLs) of files.
CALL            Calls one batch program from another.
CD              Displays the name of or changes the current directory.
CHCP            Displays or sets the active code page number.
CHDIR           Displays the name of or changes the current directory.
CHKDSK          Checks a disk and displays a status report.
CHKNTFS         Displays or modifies the checking of disk at boot time.
CLS             Clears the screen.
CMD             Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter.
COLOR           Sets the default console foreground and background colors.
COMP            Compares the contents of two files or sets of files.
COMPACT         Displays or alters the compression of files on NTFS partitions.
CONVERT         Converts FAT volumes to NTFS.  You cannot convert the current drive.
COPY            Copies one or more files to another location.
DATE            Displays or sets the date.
DEL             Deletes one or more files.
DIR             Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.
DISKPART        Displays or configures Disk Partition properties.
DOSKEY          Edits command lines, recalls Windows commands, and creates macros.
DRIVERQUERY     Displays current device driver status and properties.
ECHO            Displays messages, or turns command echoing on or off.
ENDLOCAL        Ends localization of environment changes in a batch file.
ERASE           Deletes one or more files.
EXIT            Quits the CMD.EXE program (command interpreter).
FC              Compares two files or sets of files, and displays the differences between them.
FIND            Searches for a text string in a file or files.
FINDSTR         Searches for strings in files.
FOR             Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
FORMAT          Formats a disk for use with Windows.
FSUTIL          Displays or configures the file system properties.
FTYPE           Displays or modifies file types used in file extension associations.
GOTO            Directs the Windows command interpreter to a labeled line in a batch program.
GPRESULT        Displays Group Policy information for machine or user.
GRAFTABL        Enables Windows to display an extended character set in graphics mode.
HELP            Provides Help information for Windows commands.
ICACLS          Display, modify, backup, or restore ACLs for files and directories.
IF              Performs conditional processing in batch programs.
LABEL           Creates, changes, or deletes the volume label of a disk.
MD              Creates a directory.
MKDIR           Creates a directory.
MKLINK          Creates Symbolic Links and Hard Links
MODE            Configures a system device.
MORE            Displays output one screen at a time.
MOVE            Moves one or more files from one directory to another directory.
OPENFILES       Displays files opened by remote users for a file share.
PATH            Displays or sets a search path for executable files.
PAUSE           Suspends processing of a batch file and displays a message.
POPD            Restores the previous value of the current directory saved by PUSHD.
PRINT           Prints a text file.
PROMPT          Changes the Windows command prompt.
PUSHD           Saves the current directory then changes it.
RD              Removes a directory.
RECOVER         Recovers readable information from a bad or defective disk.
REM             Records comments (remarks) in batch files or CONFIG.SYS.
REN             Renames a file or files.
RENAME          Renames a file or files.
REPLACE         Replaces files.
RMDIR           Removes a directory.
ROBOCOPY        Advanced utility to copy files and directory trees
SET             Displays, sets, or removes Windows environment variables.
SETLOCAL        Begins localization of environment changes in a batch file.
SC              Displays or configures services (background processes).
SCHTASKS        Schedules commands and programs to run on a computer.
SHIFT           Shifts the position of replaceable parameters in batch files.
SHUTDOWN       Allows proper local or remote shutdown of machine.
SORT            Sorts input.
START           Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
SUBST           Associates a path with a drive letter.
SYSTEMINFO     Displays machine specific properties and configuration.
TASKLIST        Displays all currently running tasks including services.
TASKKILL        Kill or stop a running process or application.
TIME            Displays or sets the system time.
TITLE           Sets the window title for a CMD.EXE session.
TREE            Graphically displays the directory structure of a drive or path.
TYPE            Displays the contents of a text file.
VER             Displays the Windows version.
VERIFY          Tells Windows whether to verify that your files are written correctly to a disk.
VOL             Displays a disk volume label and serial number.
XCOPY           Copies files and directory trees.
WMIC            Displays WMI information inside interactive command shell.

I could not find any nmp command in this Help file. Can someone help me to show me how to copy this Moralis file onto my computer.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You sure it is `nmp` instead of `npm`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I did receive the answer from a contributor and needed to install NPM on my laptop. After that no issues in the command "npm install -g moralis-admin cli".

Comment: It's not an answer.It's a comment!

Comment: In my answer I was trying to explain that I had submitted this query and before further comment was added to it an answer had been given to me and the query was answered.